# Stay on same page but data should be transfer to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple text field in my form and i want to transfer the data of fields to another page using jquery but user should stay on same page. Only javascript code please.

Comment: This is not a "Write this for me" service.  What you are describing is called AJAX - go check out some articles about jQuery AJAX and if you have a specific problem, you can ask _that_ question.

Comment: I am using jQuery in my project thats why i asked for it. I haven't used ajax so i don't know about it.

Comment: If you know how to do it uaing ajax than please tell me.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many, many times.  This site is not intended to reproduce existing answers, it's intended to provide new, useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's AJAX API](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), allowing you to make your own HTTP requests.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType

});
```

- Assuming you are trying to process the data and transfer it, with the use of a server.

LocalStorage can also be used to store key-value sets of data on the users hard-drive. This data will only be available to your specific domain, but the is free to alter it, as it is on their computer.

Comment: Can i send multiple values using this?

Comment: Yes, Data can be of any form, so you can use array or object, you may need to serialise.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your desire to help is great.  However, this is NOT a good question for SO, and you should not answer it.  Instead, you should vote to close (once you have enough reputation).

Comment: You should not impose people vote to close a question, especially if they do not want to. If you do not want to help, but vote to close the question, you can do so. @cale_b

Comment: I understand.  However, you should familiarize yourself with the StackOverflow policies.  I'm trying to _coach you_, not "impose you" to close.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322096/870729

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in mind, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or [sessionStorage](https://www.google.com.gt/search?q=sessionstorage&oq=sessionstorage&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.1632j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to pass them through pages. No jquery needed.

Comment: But i want user to stay on same page

Comment: @Piyush - You misunderstand the answer.  Further, since you haven't told us what you intend to do with the info on another page, it's very difficult to provide you with a good answer.

Comment: Ok i tell you why i want to do this. Actually my project uses both html pages and wordpress blog and both are on different server because blog is having some problems when i move it to the other server where html pages are stored. So i want to store all the data from forms in database of 1 server. Thats why i want to send the data from blog page to my html page and than to database.

Comment: @Piyush Both HTML and wordpress has forms? If so, you will need that both pages make an ajax to the same database but only once. Your requirements still not clear.

Comment: See my requirement is i want to make one single single database for both the server. And i want to send the data of WordPress form to my php page on html server but the user should be on my same wordpress page after submitting the form. This data will automatically stored in my database through my php code. I just want to pass my data from wordpress form page to my php file on another server that's it.

Comment: My database is on server where my html files are stored. And yes both html and wordpress has forms

Comment: So if the data are stored in the same database, you only need to read it in from both sides... Doesnt look like 'setting data' issue as your question says.